# A differentiable function that is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ which has a derivative that is not

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $E$ be a compact subset of a bounded open set $\mathcal{D},$ both of which are subsets of the real numbers. Let a differentiable function $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(1), \forall x\in\mathcal{D}.$ Is there an $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)\neq\mathcal{O}(1)$, for some$ x\in E?$ I've attempted to construct functions that oscillate wildly at a point, but couldn't find one that didn't have a derivative that was $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: What do you mean by saying something is $O(1)$ for all $x$?  $O(1)$ is generally a statement of asymptotics.  Are you saying you want it to hold UNIFORMLY?  That is, you want an analytic function that is bounded, but whose derivative is not bounded?

Comment: I was asking something I didn't intend to. I've edited the question and hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: $x^{1/2}$ is analytic on $x > 0$ and its derivative is unbounded as $x \to 0$. Of course you can't take $E$ compact since an analytic function (on an open containing $E$) is (and all its derivative) uniformly bounded on $E$

Comment: Since analytic functions have all derivatives, they cannot have an unbounded derivative, in a point of the set itself, since the second derivative still needs to exist.

Comment: Also if $f$ is complex analytic on $0 <|z| < 1$ and $f'$ is unbounded at $z=0$ then [so is $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). Thus the point where $f'$ diverges can't be an isolated singularity.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I agree. I've weakened the assumption from analyticity to differentiability. I'm unsure of whether or not I should have done that or if I should delete the question at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $E = [-1,1]$, and $\mathcal D = (-2, 2)$. Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $x = 0$},\\ x^2\sin(x^{-3}) &\text{else.}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is trivially bounded on $\mathcal D$. Also, the derivative of $f$ exists on all of $\mathcal D$: we have
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $x = 0$},\\ 2x\sin(x^{-3}) - 3x^{-2}\cos(x^{-3}) &\text{else,}\end{cases}$$
which clearly is not bounded near $x = 0$.

Comment: Why is this $f$ analytic on $D$?

Comment: It isn't analytic at $0$